# Polytopes that are just defined by ordering the variables

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

I am working with a polytope with a very specific structure, namely that it is characterized entirely by placing the variables, or the variables plus constants, or just constants, in a particular order.  A completely arbitrary example of this would be $$0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_1 + 4 \leq x_3 \leq x_2 + 3 \leq 8 \leq x_3 + 4 \leq x_1 + 9 \leq 100$$
My questions:  is there any name for such polytopes, or anything related?  Also, is there any nice way to exploit this structure in order to enumerate the vertices of such a polytope?

Comment: These polytopes are partial cases of the Lipschitz polytopes, defined by a quasi-metric space $(X,\rho)$ and consisting of functions $f$ on $X$ satisfying $f(x)-f(y)\leqslant \rho(x,y)$ for $x,y$ in $X$. Such functions are defined up to additive constant, in other words, we may fix a point $a\in X$ and fix the value $f(a)=0$. In your example you may replace $0,100$ to $x_0,x_0+100$, then each inequality in your chain is of above type.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your polytopes are a subset of the polytopes where every inequality has at most two variables with non-zero coefficient.

Those are studied in [On the Complexity of Polytopes in $LI(2)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.10114) by Komei Fukuda, May Szedlak, 2017.

(Here "$LI(2)$" denotes exactly those polytopes)